# Locale not supported by C library when running Thunderbird

Tags: locale

Thunderbird still runs fine but it says:

> Using fallback 'C' locale.

`en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` has been uncommented in `locale.gen`.

`LANG=en_US.UTF-8` has been put in `locale.conf`.

`locale-gen` has been run.

Desktop environment is KDE Plasma.

Output of `locale` (first three lines not present when run inside a virtual terminal instead of the desktop environment):

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory   
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory   
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory   
LANG=cic_US.UTF-8  
LC_CTYPE="cic_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="cic_US.UTF-8"  
LC_TIME="cic_US.UTF-8"  
LC_COLLATE="cic_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="cic_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="cic_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="cic_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="cic_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="cic_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="cic_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="cic_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="cic_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

It also happens when running GParted so it's not Thunderbird exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Something is overriding your `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and setting `LANG=cic_US.UTF-8` instead.

Perhaps `grep -r cic_US.UTF-8 /etc $HOME/.??* 2>/dev/null` (run as the user having the issue) might reveal where that incorrect `LANG` value is getting set?

Also check System Settings -> Regional Settings in KDE, as it apparently can be used to set locale combinations that may be supported by KDE but not necessarily supported by the rest of the system.